# Displaying 2D associative array with angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, typescript, angular

I would like to display my 2D associative array but I don't know well the syntax of angular 2 in HTML. Can someone help me ?

My associative array :

```
parents = [
       parent1:[child1,child2,child3],
       parent2:[child4,child5],
       parent3:[child6]
      ];
```

In my .html I would like to have something like that :

```
<div *ngFor="let parent of parents">
    {{parent name}}
    <div *ngFor="let child of parent">
         {{child name}}
      </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

arrays can't have named keys, so you'll need to convert your arrays to objects (or `map`s), then you can iterate their keys.

```
parents = { 
       parent1: { 
         child1: "1"
       } 
}

for (var parentKey in parents) {
    // parentKey --> parent1
    for (var childKey in parents[parentKey]) 
        // childKey --> child1
}
```

you can use the above pattern in your angular template.